# Photoshop Save for web does'nt retain transparency

Tags: photoshop

I have been trying to save for web from a psd file, The .PNG file that I get has no transparency and instead all transparent area is filled with white.

I am beginner in Photoshop, How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Are you setting it to preserve transparency on save? Flattering your layers to one layer results in transparent pixels shifting to white, at least back in PS 5

Comment: http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/photoshop/transparent/background.html

Comment: http://bit.ly/1fS9bff

Comment: @Anthony yes I am selecting transparency check box. The PSD shows it to be transparent but the output png is'nt

Comment: @Anthony I already have a file with transparent areas

Comment: Before or after you flatten it?

Comment: Having a transparent base layer is not the same as a transparent image. Did you see the video tutorials on this in the search results? Have you asked at : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-convert-a-transparent-photoshop-psd-to-a-png-for-the-internet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally if you are doing save for web in png 8 format it will take white color instead of transparency to avoid this white color You have to do save for web as png 24 format then u will get transparency without white color

Answer (score 1):

The Problem got Solved, the App/program i was using had some problem and was not showing the background to be transparent, have tried it on another program and its OK

Thanks to Anthony who helped alot.